# Marking text issues with a fixed div

Tags: html, css, css-position

The problem is visible when you change the width of the site (make it smaller). The moment the fixed div is above the table, proper marking of the text is impossible (it's especially visible with the first column which is small). When the fixed div is not above the table I can mark the text without problem.

I've made some screenshots, I hope they'll clear up the situation: in the first picture it works fine, but in the second, after making the width smaller, the problem is clearly visible - a text above the text that I want to mark is actually being marked.

[image: Here it works fine]

[image: Here's the problem]
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share your code, so it's easier for us to help you :)

Comment: Try margin-left:30px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css and it will be fixed. Because the div is front of the table cells, it prevents you from marking the cells.

```
div#floating-form {
 height: 145px;
}

@media (max-width: 675px)
   div#floating-form {
     height: 75px;
   }
}
```

Comment: the problem was also with higher resolutions like 1280px. But you gave me the hint, I've added `height:90px` to the `div#floating-form` for all resolutions form but also `overflow:visible`. Now it works, thank you!

Comment: but the whole `div#floating-form` has got 450px so I need the `overflow:visible` anyway. Thank for the answer, you've helped me a lot ;)